# Loopback Custom Model Route

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

The documentation is not really descriptive here for LoopBack, so I am asking on here how to create a custom URI route for the model itself. I want to combine a few API servers into one large server and separate said API servers off the top. For example:

```
http://myapi.com/app1/v1/model
http://myapi.com/app2/v1/model
```

The workaround I have would be to create separate projects for each application and use nginx for routing. However since this is a suite of applications which somewhat shares resources, that would be time consuming to build the shared models with custom functions, then copy that over to the second project.

Any solution folks? This seems relatively simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the path you want to use in the Model config: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Exposing-models-over-REST.html#rest-paths